# Using balloons in attack

Tags: clash-of-clans

What do balloons target? In the description it says "ground" but they seem to go specifically for the defense structures. Is this correct?

Also when I'm dropping healing or rage spells they seem not to get used as the balloons move away to the next target instead of going to the closest structure. Any advice on where and how to drop the spells?

Answer (score 3):

In a defensive position, balloons can only hit ground targets. They can kill barbarians, archers, etc., but they can't kill other balloons, dragons, minions, etc.

In an offensive position, however, they will always attack and prioritize the defense structures, no matter what situation it is. The nearer the balloon is to a defensive structure, that's the top priority.

For effective potion usage, try dropping it where the enemy's DEFENSIVE structures are; archer towers, wizard towers, cannons, etc.

Comment: Thanks, would you say to drop balloons near ad first, or far away with them to start with? I red drop them close so they can take them out, but it seems wasteful if you bring in other troops to actually destroy the other buildings.

Comment: @celeritas you should deploy in such a way that the balloons get near the air defenses getting least hits..  you could use rage to get them clear defenses faster..  drop them in the area where you think there is a group of defenses and the balloons are heading towards it..

Answer (score 1):

**Balloons target Defenses, and only after destroying them all, they will target other ground targets.** A good idea is to drop a Healing Spell when they took heavy splash damage, such as from a Wizard Tower, and a Rage / Haste Spell when they are inside a large cluster of defenses.